# Trying to import Bitcoin ATM wallet into Armory

Tags: wallet, private-key, armory, bitcoin-atm

I withdrew Bitcoins from Bitcoin ATM (Bitcoin mainnet, if that matters) into a wallet that it generated for me.  My intention was to import or sweep the generated wallet into Armory (or possibly Bitcoin Core).  [Warning: Newbie alert!]

The first thing I realized was the public and private keys that the ATM generated for me were in WIF format, and Armory seems to only want hex keys.  So I discovered pycoin and used ku.py to convert WIF to a hex secret exponent.  Armory seemed happy enough with the hex exponent, and asked me to confirm the apparent Bitcoin address.  The address was correct, so I confirmed and Armory began scanning something or other.  When it finally finished scanning, it told me there appeared to be no funds associated with the address.

The only people who saw the private key are myself and the ATM, and I'll assume it reasonably unlikely that the ATM was compromised.  If true, my funds still exist somewhere, but I don't know how or where to find them.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For what it's worth, the ATM vendor confirmed that the transaction was going and gave me a blockchain.info link that shows the funds still there.

Comment: The ATM vendor recommended the blockchain.info app.  Once I installed that, I was easily able to scan and import the private key into a new wallet.  I completed my transaction directly from the wireless device and deleted Armory and Bitcoin Core with its 50+ GB of data from my desktop.  No doubt this has security ramifications, bad or neutral, which I will try to reassess at some point.  I was unable to get Armory to import the private key and wallet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very curious why does Armory scan the private key I have imported takes for a long time.

However, sweeping a bitcoin from a paper wallet should be very simple.
Install and use a Mycelium wallet app on your phone. Scan the QR private key on the paper wallet and send it to the Armory's QR receiving address.

In this case, you are using the Mycelium wallet as a bridge and nothing is compromised. You can also just throw away the paper wallet.

Just maybe the problem is with pycoin. I'm trying to use an offline bitaddress.org to import my private key to Armory.